# Getting all Facebook friends using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to GET "me/friends" and the returned JSON contains 3 less friends than my Facebook page shows that I have. It turned out that for those 3, GET "/[id]" returns false as opposed to a valid JSON object, although I don't see anything special about them except that they might haven't used Facebook for a while. Originally I thought this was a bug but I was told this was as-designed. If that's the case, how do I get a full list of my current Fb friends, presumably via Graph API?

Comment: Did you find the reason mobileTofu? I experienced same problem while using /me/friends, that not all friends are listed. I was wondering that the number of friends in the list varies by time. For testing a friend of mine was using my app a couple of times...by analyzing the number of friends shown to my app i saw that each time he accessed my app the number of friends showing was different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Users can opt out of the Facebook platform entirely by going to Privacy Settings -> Apps and Websites:

[image]

Comment: So i guess Facebook itself is not considered a platform app.

Comment: Correct - nor are its official ipad/iphone/android apps.

Comment: So the answer is there's no sure way to get how many friends a user has via Graph API...? I will give it another shot when I find time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the cause. I was also struggling with this case. Using taggable_friends instead of friends will bring your friends.

The point is that "friends" for facebook are those who use the same APP you are using/doing.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class FbLogin extends AppCompatActivity {
    String fb_data_url = "url";
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    LoginManager loginManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fb_login);

        fb_login_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                errorMsg.setText("");
                facebookLogin();
            }
        });


        // Facebook login integration get all detail
        loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                fbDialog.isShowing();
                final AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("FaceBookAccessToken", accessToken.getToken());
                editor.apply();

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        JSONObject fbJsonObjResponse = response.getJSONObject();
                        Log.e("FbResponse", response.toString());
                        try {
                            if (fbJsonObjResponse.has("id") && fbJsonObjResponse.getInt("id") > 0 && fbJsonObjResponse.has("birthday")) {

                                fb_id_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("id");
                                fb_name_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("name");
                                fb_gender_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("gender");
                                locale_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("locale");
                                time_zone_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("timezone");

                                fb_birthday_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("birthday");

                                if (fb_birthday_str != null && !fb_birthday_str.equals("") && !fb_birthday_str.equals("null")) {

                                } else {
                                    fb_birthday_str = "2018-02-14T08:13:18.951786+00:00";
                                }

                                String[] dob_format_arr = fb_birthday_str.split("/");
                                String dob_format_month = dob_format_arr[0];
                                String dob_format_day = dob_format_arr[1];
                                String dob_format_year = dob_format_arr[2];

                                String age = getAge(Integer.parseInt(dob_format_year), Integer.parseInt(dob_format_month), Integer.parseInt(dob_format_day));
                                editor.putString("FbUserId", fb_id_str);
                                editor.putString("UserName", fb_name_str);
                                editor.putString("UserAge", age);
                                editor.apply();

                                fb_about_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("about");
                                if (fb_about_str != null && !fb_about_str.equals("") && !fb_about_str.equals("null")) {

                                } else {
                                    fb_about_str = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.not_available);
                                }

                                fb_email_id_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("email");
                                if (fb_email_id_str != null && !fb_email_id_str.equals("") && !fb_email_id_str.equals("null")) {
                                } else {
                                    fb_email_id_str = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.not_available);
                                }

                                fb_educationObj = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("education");
                                if (fb_educationObj != null && !fb_educationObj.equals("") && !fb_educationObj.equals("null")) {
                                    JSONArray json_school = fbJsonObjResponse.optJSONArray("education");
                                    JSONObject json_school_obj = json_school.getJSONObject(0);
                                    JSONObject json_sc_obj = json_school_obj.optJSONObject("school");
                                    for (int j = 0; j < json_sc_obj.length(); j++) {
                                        education_str = json_sc_obj.optString("name");
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    education_str = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.not_available);
                                }

                                JSONObject fbLocation = new JSONObject();
                                fb_location_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("location");
                                if (fb_location_str != null && !fb_location_str.equals("null") && !fb_location_str.equals("")) {
                                    JSONObject json_location_obj = fbJsonObjResponse.optJSONObject("location");
                                    JSONObject jsonLocationObj = json_location_obj.optJSONObject("location");
                                    city_str = jsonLocationObj.optString("city");
                                    country_str = jsonLocationObj.optString("country");
                                    String locationID = json_location_obj.optString("id");
                                    fbLocation.put("id", locationID);
                                    fbLocation.put("name", city_str);
                                } else {
                                    fbLocation = new JSONObject();
                                    city_str = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.not_available);
                                    country_str = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.not_available);
                                }

                                String firebase_token = sharedPreferences.getString("regId", null);

                                favorite_teams_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("favorite_teams");
                                JSONArray favorite_teamArray;
                                if (favorite_teams_str != null && !favorite_teams_str.equals("") && !favorite_teams_str.equals("null")) {
                                    favorite_teamArray = fbJsonObjResponse.optJSONArray("favorite_teams");
                                } else {
                                    favorite_teamArray = new JSONArray();
                                }
                                favorite_athletes_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("favorite_athletes");
                                JSONArray favorite_athletesArray;
                                if (favorite_athletes_str != null && !favorite_athletes_str.equals("") && !favorite_athletes_str.equals("null")) {
                                    favorite_athletesArray = fbJsonObjResponse.optJSONArray("favorite_athletes");
                                } else {
                                    favorite_athletesArray = new JSONArray();
                                }

                                fb_education_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("education");
                                JSONArray educationArray;
                                if (fb_education_str != null && !fb_education_str.equals("") && !fb_education_str.equals("null")) {
                                    educationArray = fbJsonObjResponse.optJSONArray("education");
                                } else {
                                    educationArray = new JSONArray();
                                }

                                fb_work_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("work");
                                JSONArray json_workArray;
                                if (fb_work_str != null && !fb_work_str.equals("") && !fb_work_str.equals("null")) {
                                    json_workArray = object.optJSONArray("work");
                                    JSONObject json_work_object = json_workArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                    JSONObject json_work_obj = json_work_object.optJSONObject("employer");
                                    {
                                        company_name_str = json_work_obj.optString("name");
                                    }
                                    String str_position_name = json_work_object.optString("position");

                                    if (str_position_name != null && !str_position_name.equals("") && !str_position_name.equals("null")) {
                                        JSONObject json_worker_pos = json_work_object.optJSONObject("position");
                                        position_name_str = json_worker_pos.optString("name");
                                    } else {
                                        //position_name_str = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.not_available);
                                        position_name_str = "";
                                    }

                                } else {
                                    json_workArray = new JSONArray();
                                    company_name_str = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.not_available);
                                }

                                movies_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("movies");
                                JSONArray moviesArray;
                                if (movies_str != null && !movies_str.equals("null") && !movies_str.equals("")) {
                                    JSONObject moviesObject = new JSONObject(movies_str);
                                    moviesArray = moviesObject.optJSONArray("data");
                                } else {
                                    moviesArray = new JSONArray();
                                }
                                musics_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("music");
                                JSONArray musicArray;
                                if (musics_str != null && !musics_str.equals("") && !musics_str.equals("null")) {
                                    JSONObject musicObject = new JSONObject(musics_str);
                                    musicArray = musicObject.optJSONArray("data");
                                } else {
                                    musicArray = new JSONArray();
                                }
                                books_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("books");
                                JSONArray bookSArray;
                                if (books_str != null && !books_str.equals("") && !books_str.equals("null")) {
                                    JSONObject booksObject = new JSONObject(books_str);
                                    bookSArray = booksObject.optJSONArray("data");
                                } else {
                                    bookSArray = new JSONArray();
                                }
                                tv_shows_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("television");
                                JSONArray televisionArray;
                                if (tv_shows_str != null && !tv_shows_str.equals("") && !tv_shows_str.equals("null")) {
                                    JSONObject televisionObject = new JSONObject(tv_shows_str);
                                    televisionArray = televisionObject.optJSONArray("data");
                                } else {
                                    televisionArray = new JSONArray();
                                }

                                home_town_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("hometown");
                                JSONObject json_homeTown_obj;
                                if (home_town_str != null && !home_town_str.equals("") && !home_town_str.equals("null")) {
                                    json_homeTown_obj = fbJsonObjResponse.optJSONObject("hometown");
                                } else {
                                    json_homeTown_obj = new JSONObject();
                                    json_homeTown_obj.put("id", "");
                                    json_homeTown_obj.put("name", "");
                                }

                                relationship_status = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("relationship_status");
                                if (relationship_status != null && !relationship_status.equals("") && !relationship_status.equals("null")) {
                                    relationship_status_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("relationship_status");
                                } else {
                                    relationship_status_str = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.not_available);
                                }

                                JSONArray likesArray;
                                fb_Likes_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("likes");
                                if (fb_Likes_str != null && !fb_Likes_str.equals("") && !fb_Likes_str.equals("null")) {
                                    JSONObject likesObject = new JSONObject(fb_Likes_str);
                                    likesArray = likesObject.optJSONArray("data");
                                } else {
                                    likesArray = new JSONArray();
                                }

                                JSONArray friendArr = new JSONArray();
                                friends_str = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("friends");
                                if (friends_str != null && !friends_str.equals("") && !friends_str.equals("null")) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(friends_str);
                                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("data");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                        JSONObject jsonFriend = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
                                        friend_str_ids = jsonFriend.optString("id");
                                        jsonObject1.put("id", friend_str_ids);
                                        friendArr.put(jsonObject1);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    friendArr = new JSONArray();
                                }

                                user_albums = fbJsonObjResponse.optString("albums");
                                if (user_albums != null && !user_albums.equals("") && !user_albums.equals("null")) {
                                    JSONObject jsonAlbumObj = new JSONObject(user_albums);
                                    JSONArray jsonAlbumArray = jsonAlbumObj.optJSONArray("data");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonAlbumArray.length(); i++) {
                                        JSONObject json_album = jsonAlbumArray.optJSONObject(i);

                                        String album_type = json_album.optString("type");
                                        if (album_type.contains("profile")) {
                                            album_id_str = json_album.getString("id");
                                        } else {
                                            //album_id_str = "";
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    //album_id_str = "";
                                }

                            } catch(JSONException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e("Create User Exception", e.getMessage());
                            }
                            Log.e("createUser", createUser.toString());
                            // Volley response fetch
                            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
                                    com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, fb_data_url, createUser,
                                    new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                            try {
                                                Log.e("Create User ", response.toString());
                                                String apiResponse = response.getString("ApiResponse");
                                                String UserPref = response.getString("UserPref");
                                                String gender;
                                                if (UserPref.equals("m")) {
                                                    gender = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.male);
                                                } else if (UserPref.equals("f")) {
                                                    gender = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.female);
                                                } else {
                                                    gender = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.male_female_both);
                                                }
                                                editor.putString("InterestedInSp", gender);
                                                editor.apply();
                                                if ((apiResponse.contains("Error"))) {
                                                    errorMsg.setText(apiResponse);
                                                } else {
                                                    editor.putString("fbLogging", "fbLogging");
                                                    JSONObject UserAuth_obj = response.getJSONObject("UserAuth");
                                                    MyUserID_str = UserAuth_obj.getString("MyUserID");
                                                    MyUserToken_str = UserAuth_obj.getString("MyUserToken");
                                                    editor.putString("MyUserIDSp", MyUserID_str);
                                                    editor.putString("MyUserTokenSp", MyUserToken_str);
                                                    editor.apply();
                                                    fbDialog.dismiss();
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(FbLogin.this, Home.class));
                                                }
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    fbDialog.dismiss();
                                    errorMsg.setText("You Don~t have Permission Compulsory");
                                    Log.e("Error_Response", error.toString());
                                }
                            }) {
                                @Override
                                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                                    return headers;
                                }
                            };
                            Apps.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
                        } else{
                            fbDialog.dismiss();
                            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                            errorMsg.setText("Permission Compulsory");
                            Toast.makeText(FbLogin.this, "Technical issue by user data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch(
                    JSONException e)

                    {
                        fbDialog.dismiss();
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                        errorMsg.setText("Permission Compulsory");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields","id,email,name,gender,birthday,about,picture.type(large),location{location},"+
                        "favorite_athletes,hometown,favorite_teams,education,work,movies,music,books,television,likes.limit(100){id,name,category,created_time},"+
                        "relationship_status,locale,timezone,friends,albums.limit(100){id,type}");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel () {
            fbDialog.dismiss();
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            errorMsg.setText("Permission Compulsory");
            Toast.makeText(FbLogin.this, "Login Cancelled...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError (FacebookException exception){
            fbDialog.dismiss();
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            errorMsg.setText("Permission Compulsory");
            Toast.makeText(FbLogin.this, "Check your internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        }

private void facebookLogin(){
        fbDialog=new ProgressDialog(FbLogin.this);
        fbDialog.setProgressStyle(0);
        fbDialog.setMessage(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.fetch_fb_data));
        fbDialog.show();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this,
        Arrays.asList("public_profile,email,user_birthday,user_location,user_hometown,user_about_me,user_likes,user_education_history,user_work_history,user_relationships,user_friends,user_photos"));
        }

        }
```

Comment: Don't just post code, please add some comments on the context of your post or it will be deleted. Thanks