# Facebook get friends id

Tags: android, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting all Facebook friends using Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514664/getting-all-facebook-friends-using-graph-api)

I'm trying to get all of my friends facebook IDs on Android. This is the code I use:

```
public static List<String> getFaceBookFriendsIDs() {

        List<String> friendsList = null;
        try {
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject(ParseFacebookUtils.getFacebook().request("me/friends"));
            JSONArray friendsArray = result.getJSONArray("data");

            friendsList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < friendsArray.length(); i++) {
                friendsList.add(friendsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
            }
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return friendsList;

    }
```

The sise of the list however is not the same value as the number of friends I have. Is that normal, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Use RestFB API ! [see here](http://restfb.com/#fetching-connections)
Makes everything easier and generates (maybe) some overhead, but still, it's probably easier.